# Компилятор g++ флаги, оптимизация, сборка

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Изучаю работу с g++ интересует линковка, генерация кода, оптимизация, g++ содержит множество флагов оптимизаций помимо `-O1 ... -Ofast`. Хотелось бы почитать за эти оптимизации и понять что и где лучше использовать (желательно на русском).

Есть хорошие материалы на эту тему?

Здесь буду выписывать полезные ключи для компилятора

---

### Стандарты С++

- `-std=c++98` - C++98
- `-std=c++11` - C++11
- `-std=c++14` - C++14
- `-std=c++17` - C++17
- `-std=c++2a` - C++20

---

### Предупреждения

- `-Wall` - Выводит большинство предупреждений
- `-Wfloat-equal` - Предупреждает о не безопасном сравнении
- `-Wsign-conversion` или `-Wsign-promo` - Предупреждения преобразования signed в unsigned (и обратно)
- `-Wold-style-cast` - Выводит C Style преобразования типов
- `-Warray-bounds` - Доступ за пределы массива
- `-Wdiv-by-zero` - Предупреждать о делении на 0
- `-Wdouble-promotion` - Предупреждает о преобразовании с `float` на `double`
- `-Wbool-compire` - Предупреждение о сравнении `int` с `bool`

---

### Сборка

Для сборки программы необходимо указать компилятору g++ файлы исходного кода, например команда `g++ main.cpp` скомпилирует исходный код файла `main.cpp` в исполняемый фаил `a.out` *(если компилятору не указать имя выходного файла то по умолчанию именем будет `a.out`)*

- `-o <name>` - Имя выходного файла

  **Пример:** Команда `g++ -o myexe main.cpp` скомпилирует фаил `main.cpp` в исполняемый фаил `myexe`.

  Можно передавать несколько исходных файлов для сборки, например `g++ -o myexe file1.cpp file2.cpp`.
- `-c` - Создание [объектного файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C)

  **Пример:** Для создания объектного файла необходимо указать компилятору ключи `-c` и `-o`: `g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp`, данной командой компилятор g++ создает объектный фаил `main.o` из файла `main.cpp`

  Для сборки программы из объектных файлов необходимо указать компилятору в качестве входных параметров не файлы исходного кода а объектные файлы: `g++ -o myexe foo.o main.o bar.o` - создает программу из объектных файлов `foo.o main.o bar.o`
- `-I<include_path>` - Указание каталога для поиска подключаемых файлов

  **Пример:** `g++ -o myexe -I/my/path/to/include main.cpp`
- `-L<library_path>` - Указание каталога для поиска библиотек
- `-l<library>` - Указание конкретной библиотеки для линковки

---

### Полезные материалы

Книга Артура Гриффитса - "GCC полное руководство"

---

P.S. `g++ --help` известно =)

Спасибо: [Croessmah](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189960/croessmah)

Comment: Гугл :) [опции gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_2.html)

Comment: Еще есть книга Артура Гриффитса - "GCC полное руководство"

Comment: `-jN` - не опция GCC. Это опция всяких `make`, `cmake`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat исправил

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соответствует формату Q&A.

Comment: Самый вредный флаг `-fexception` рекомендую запомнить и удалять как увидите :) немедленно. Причина: `Если исключение распространяется на функцию, которая была скомпилирована без поддержки исключений, программа завершается.`

Comment: `-march` и `-mcpu` забыл :)

Answer (score 3):

Если быстро и на английском то так :

```
user@comp:path> man g++ > дока
```

и в текстовом редакторе читаете эту `дока`. Можно начинать доступно по русски там:
[Изучаем параметры gcc](http://gentoo.theserverside.ru/gentoo-doc/Gentoo_doc-1.5-50.html)